# jQuery Ajax function request lost connection at nearly 5 minute ONLY in Safari browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis, safari

My website is in PHP and I am sending a request to server using below code.

```
//Ajax throuth download pdf report
ajaxDownloadReport = function(formId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#hidOverlay').val(),
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        timeout: 0,
        cache: false,
        data: $("#" + formId).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            ProgressMsg("Please wait a minute.");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox.close();
            data = $.trim(data);
            arrData = data.split("|||");
            window.open(arrData[0]);
            return true;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(textStatus==="timeout") {  
                alert("Call has timed out"); //Handle the timeout
            } else {
                alert("Another error was returned. "); //Handle other error type
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This function is used to generate reports for selected users. It is working fine in all browsers except Safari browser in MAC OS.
If user send request to generate 10-15 users then It is working fine in safari browser but If user send request to generate 30 users report (MAX) then server need nearly 5-6 minute to send response. At that time only in Safari browser It gives below error after 4 minute process.

**`Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.`**

This error comes only in safari browser. In all other browser It works completely fine.

Another strange thing that, My website has 4 Production server. they all point to one URL **`production.website.com`**

If I run this site individually for each server like

**production1.website.com**

**production2.website.com**

**production3.website.com**

**production4.website.com**

Then This Ajax function works fine in Safari and all other browser.
But If I run website using **production.website.com** then this Ajax function is giving a connection lost error only in safari browser.

I have tried many solution like timeout, cache and header changes. But all are failed to solve this issue. My website is on **IIS** server.

Please guide me to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks In Advance..!

Comment: The fundamental issue is that five minutes is too long to have an inactive connection; something, somewhere in the path is going to give up on that connection. Is it possible to have the server send something back while the work is being done, so the connection is active? If not, you may want to break it into two requests: One that starts the process, and another that polls for the result.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes the main issue is that its taking a nearly 5-6 minute. But Its working in all other browser even in IE and Edge browser. So It should be work in Safari also. Is it possible to send something back from server while the work is in progress in PHP application?

Comment: *"Its working in all other browser even in IE and Edge browser. So It should be work in Safari also"* That's a logical fallacy. Browsers / operating systems can set their own "this has been inactive too long" policy. *"Is it possible to send something back from server while the work is in progress in PHP application?" I'm no PHP expert, but the general answer is yes, absolutely. You just send output in the normal way. But if your thread is held up doing the work, you may need another to send the interim responses; I don't know how you do that in PHP (if you can).